# Unable to convert MySql query using doctrine DQL or QueryBuilder

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I cannot convert this query :

```
SELECT c.title, COUNT(*),
(
    SELECT ba_thumb.link
    FROM ba_video
    INNER JOIN video_channel ON video_channel.video_id=ba_video.id
    INNER JOIN ba_thumb ON ba_thumb.video_id=video_channel.video_id
    INNER JOIN ba_channel ON ba_channel.id=video_channel.channel_id
    WHERE video_channel.channel_id=c.id
    ORDER BY ba_video.views DESC, ba_thumb.id ASC
    LIMIT 1
) AS ba_thumb_link
FROM ba_channel c
INNER JOIN video_channel ON video_channel.channel_id=c.id
INNER JOIN ba_video ON ba_video.id=video_channel.video_id
GROUP BY video_channel.channel_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

into DQL or using QueryBuilder.

I tried in DQL :

```
return $this->_em->createQuery('
            SELECT c.title, COUNT(*),
             (
                SELECT t.link
                FROM BAVideoGalleryBundle:Video v
                INNER JOIN v.channels c 
                INNER JOIN v.thumbs t 
                WHERE c.id=mc.id
                ORDER BY v.views DESC, t.id ASC
                LIMIT 1
             )
             FROM BAVideoGalleryBundle:Channel mc
             INNER JOIN BAVideoGalleryBundle:Video mv
             GROUP BY mv.Channels.id
             ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC')
             ->getResult();
```

I get :

> "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 216: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got 'LIMIT' "

And i tried using QueryBuilder :

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c.title, COUNT(*)')
    ->from('BAVideoGalleryBundle:Channel', 'mc')
    ->innerJoin('BAVideoGalleryBundle:Video', 'mv')
    ->groupBy('mv.Channels.id')
    ->orderBy('COUNT(*)', 'DESC');

$subquery = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('t.link')
    ->from('BAVideoGalleryBundle:Video', 'v')
    ->innerJoin('v.channels', 'c')
    ->innerJoin('v.thumbs', 't')
    ->where('c.id=mc.id')
    ->orderBy('v.views', 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('t.id', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();

return $query->addSelect('('.$subquery->getDql().')')
```

But correlation is not working, i get :

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 105 near 'mc.id ORDER BY': Error: 'mc'
>   is not defined

Comment: Check your `dev.log` in you app/logs. Or check your MySQL General Query Log to see what your actual query is getting converted to from doctrine.

Comment: LIMIT does not exists in DQL, you have to use `->setMaxResults(1)`

Comment: and use setFirstResult (with setMaxResults). Then to do Limit 0,10  you will have at the end of your query .....->orderBy('t.id', 'ASC')->setFirstResult(0)->setMaxResults(1)

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#first-and-max-result-items-dql-query-only

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those situations where Doctrine ORM is likely going to cause you more issues than it solves. You could:

1. Use a [native query](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) and relevant `ResultSetMapping` setup
2. Refactor your SQL query into something that Doctrine can handle in DQL. Looking at the query you have there are a number of different ways you could do it (e.g. treating the subquery as a temporary table in the FROM / JOIN part) but I can't see of a way that Doctrine DQL would allow
3. Just go for straight SQL using Doctrine DBAL. It looks like you're using `$this->_em` which makes me think you're in an `EntityRepository`, so you could do: `$this->_em->getConnection()` to get a [DBAL connection](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html) then just do `$conn->query()`. Obviously this way you lose the benefits of an ORM (database agnostic etc.) but you can think of ORMs as having a tax executing complex queries.

I understand none of these are ideal but from experience, sometimes it's better to push Doctrine ORM out of the way to achieve what you need.

Comment: More often than not, performing several simple queries is faster than a single big query with multiple joins and sub-select. So I agree with @john-noel suggestions.