# how to convert simple mysql query to doctrine Query language?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

Convert `mysql Query` to `doctrine Query` language ?

I have done the mysql and run the query in `phpmyadmin` and I'm getting returned rows :

```
select ppp.payperiod_sdesc,ppesa.gross_pay,pptpp.esi_employer_contribution,pptpp.pf_employer_contribution,pplw.employerContribution 
from py_process_emp_status_approved AS ppesa 
left join py_process_tds_pf_pt AS pptpp on ppesa.ou_code = pptpp.ou_code 
left join py_pay_group AS ppg on pptpp.pg_code = ppg.pg_code
left join py_process_labour_welfare AS pplw on ppg.pg_code = pplw.pg_code
left join py_pay_period AS ppp on pplw.payperiod_code = ppp.payperiod_code
left join py_payroll_calendar AS ppc on ppp.paycal_code = ppc.paycal_code
WHERE ppesa.ou_code = 15000 
ORDER BY ppesa.ou_code DESC 
LIMIT 0,5
```

please convert the mysql query to doctrine Query language.

Comment: stackoverflow does not exist to work for you, please try to convert it yourselft and if you fail you ask for help giving us the query you converted to check where the problem is

Comment: This is a not a code service factory, try something and ask for help if you can't do it. Start with Doctrine documentation maybe or some tuto. Here is some help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546828/unable-to-convert-mysql-query-using-doctrine-dql-or-querybuilder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to convert MySql query using doctrine DQL or QueryBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546828/unable-to-convert-mysql-query-using-doctrine-dql-or-querybuilder)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to find more guidance in the docs here: 
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/native-sql.html

Have a look at result set mapping. You can also just create a repository function to execute native sql and then call your repo function.

You can then call something like this below: 
results = getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(Your repo)->repofunction();

If your unsure how to create / call a repository function its covered multiple times in the symfony docs.

Doctrine loads all results then filters down, this is an expensive process you may be best letting sql do the work for you.

Hopefully you have everything you need to get to your end result.